# How to update a column from a subquery in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For caching reasons I need to write the Km (kilometers) field back to the location table, so far I was able to calculate the Km. Everything I am trying so far (update with unions, subqueries, etc) gives me the SQL Error 1093.

In MySQL,how do I update the Km value back to the table?

This is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `epoch_date` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float NOT NULL,
  `km` float DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `locations` (`epoch_date`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `km`) VALUES
(1429913506, -8.7285, 119.401, NULL),
(1429913631, -9.1279, 117.67, NULL),
(1429945707, -8.7063, 119.36, NULL),
(1431929523, -8.5745, 119.707, NULL),
(1431941343, -8.5773, 119.713, NULL),
(1431958383, -8.5881, 119.724, NULL),
(1431969963, -8.589, 119.728, NULL),
(1431998403, -8.5766, 119.724, NULL);
```

This is the select query that generates the KM (kilometer)

```
SELECT
    latitude
    , longitude
    , epoch_date
    , @latitude2 :=
    (
        SELECT
            latitude
        FROM locations loc1
        WHERE
            loc1.epoch_date < loc.epoch_date
        ORDER BY epoch_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
    ) as prev_latitude
    , @longitude2 :=
    (
        SELECT
            longitude
        FROM locations loc1
        WHERE
            loc1.epoch_date < loc.epoch_date
        ORDER BY epoch_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
    ) as prev_longitude
    , (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-@latitude2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-@latitude2)) *COS(RADIANS(longitude-@longitude2))) *6371) as km
FROM locations loc
ORDER BY epoch_date
```

Here is a link to the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f95de/2/0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your use of variables in the `select` statement is not guaranteed to work.  MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of expressions in a `select`, so the variables could be assigned in any order.  Depending on the order of evaluation is dangerous.

Once you solve that problem (probably by using a subquery), you can update the `km` column by using a subquery:

```
update locations l join
       (<your query here>) u
       on l.latitude = u.latitude and l.longitude = u.longitude
    set l.km = u.km;
```

Oh, I see something else dangerous as well.  You are using floating point numbers for the representation of lat and long.  You should really be using decimals, typically something like `decimal(10, 6)` is sufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up functions to return the prev_latitude and pre_longitude and use that in your `UPDATE` query.

Something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION prev_latitude(epoch INT)
  RETURNS FLOAT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE lat FLOAT;
  SET lat = null;

  SELECT latitude INTO lat
  FROM locations
  WHERE epoch_date < epoch
  ORDER BY epoch_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;

  RETURN lat;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION prev_longitude(epoch INT)
  RETURNS FLOAT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE lon FLOAT;
  SET lon = null;

  SELECT longitude INTO lon
  FROM locations
  WHERE epoch_date < epoch
  ORDER BY epoch_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;

  RETURN lon;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And your update query can now be written as

```
UPDATE locations
SET km = (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-prev_latitude(epoch_date))) +SIN(RADIANS(90-latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-prev_latitude(epoch_date))) *COS(RADIANS(longitude-prev_longitude(epoch_date)))) *6371);
```